# Use Low Power Arduino with Solar Panel

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, battery, temperature-sensor, solar

I am trying to create an arduino system with radio-transmitters and radio-receivers. The system runs from a rechargable battery that is charged with a solar panel. I am using a **1.1W 6V solar panel**.

My problem is that I don't know how to make such a connection and I don't know what batteries to choose to power the arduino, assuming that I need it to run for **5-7 days** without solar power and that the solar panel is good enough to recharge the batteries while they power the arduino. We are also assuming that the solar panel has **8 hours of sunlight**.

To the arduino are connected the following sensors:

- **Flame Sensor**
- **Light Resistor x2**
- **Smoke Sensor**
- **Radio Transmitter**
- **Radio Receiver**
- **DHT11 Temperature & Humidity Sensor**

I am also looking to see if I can power down most sensors and power them on later if an event occurs. So probably all the sensors could be sleeping except the **DHT11** and the **Radio Receiver**. Preferably though, if at all possible, the rest of the sensors should be on, if we can handle **5-7 days *without* the solar panel**. I don't know if more information is needed but I'd be pleased to help out in the comments, or provide more information by editing the question. :)

Comment: Why do you want the DHT11 to be always on?

Comment: Have a look at https://thecavepearlproject.org/ . It goes into great detail on how to run the Arduino and sensors at very low currents.

Comment: @Gerben the DHT11 needs to be one because it will be the one providing information when asked to and alert when the temperature rises. So it always needs to be on

Comment: No. The Arduino needs to be "on". The Arduino polls the DHT11, say once per minute. You could remove the power from the DHT11 when it isn't used. Then re-apply power when you need a new temperature measurement. (Though you might need to add some delay between powering up, and getting a reading).

Comment: @Gerben Yeah that was the plan, although I measured the circuit without it and constantly reading from it and it was below 1mA, so I assumed that 1mA was the average draw just to be sure, before rewriting that part of the code, taking measurements every minute instead of taking every 2 seconds without powering off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have far too many variables and unknowns there. Primarily you need to know what the average current draw for your circuit is. Secondly you need to decide how long the solar powers are allowed to take to recharge the battery. You have to think not only about runtime but also charge time. The charge time dictates the maximum capacity of the battery, and that then dictates the runtime of the Arduino. So here's some napkin maths to illustrate:

Assuming you want the battery to charge from almost flat to full within 8 hours, and with a 1.1W 6V solar cell, that gives you a peak of 183mA.

Assuming the Arduino circuit takes 83mA on average (let's give ourselves nice round numbers here) that leaves 100mA peak for charging the battery.

If you're charging at, say, 0.2C, that gives a full charge in 5 hours. 100mA / 0.2C = 500mAh capacity (at *peak sunlight and current*).

At 500mAh capacity and 83mA average current draw that would give you (0.5/0.083) 6 hours of runtime without the solar panels.

So that's just not going to work.  It'll be dead by morning.

Now assume that you can turn off *everything* for 99% of the time.  That effectively reduces our average current draw to 0.083*0.01 = 830µA. Let's plug that into the same reasoning as above.

- Current draw = 0.00083A
- Incoming peak current = 0.183
- Available charge current = 0.183-0.00083 = 0.18217
- Charge at 0.2C = 910mAh.
- 1Ah battery would charge in about 5.5 hours of peak sunlight.
- 1Ah would last about 1200 hours, or 100 days.

None of this takes into account varying light levels or light incidence angles. As a rule of thumb, take the light as averaging 50% over the course of the 8 hour period. You will only get 1.1W when the angle of incidence is 90° to the solar panel. At all other times it will be reduced. So if we reduce the current from 183mA to, say, 100mA, the charge capacity changes to:

- Incoming peak current = 0.100
- Available charge current = 0.100-0.00083 = 0.099
- Charge at 0.2C = 496mAh
- A 500mAh battery would charge in about 5 hours.
- A 500mAh battery would run for about 50 days at 830µA average current.

So you see everything really hinges around the current consumption of the Arduino. How much current it consumes dictates how much is available to charge the battery, which in turn dictates the size of battery you can support, which dictates the amount of current you can draw for your desired runtime, which in turn dictates the amount of charge current available, which determines the size of battery you can support, which dictates ... etc.  You get the idea.

You can support larger batteries, of course - I illustrated this at 0.2C charge rate (that's 20% charge per hour to give a 5 hour charge time). As long as the net charge over time increases (so during the periods between the 5-7 days of complete darkness you gain more charge than is expended during the dark period - something which has not been specified) then it should function fine.

Also note that your battery voltage should be below your solar panel voltage. A 6V solar cell would be able to charge a 4.5V lead acid battery (assuming low dropout schottky protection diodes). Also the capacity of the battery depends also on what you determine your "cut-off" voltage to be. That's how low the battery voltage is allowed to go before your system is determined to be unworkable. This could be at a point where the battery is in danger of being damaged by over-discharge, or at a point where your circuit no longer receives enough voltage to function (which could be linked to oscillator frequency on ATMega chips), etc. For this reason it is often better to choose a board that is designed to run at a lower voltage (3.3V) and use high efficiency switching regulation to get the most out of your battery. A 5V Arduino is seldom a great choice.

Finding that right balance is now entirely up to you.

And, in answer to your other question, yes there are ways to turn things on and off. You can "sleep" the Arduino. You can use high efficiency power circuits. You can add power switching circuits (P-MOSFETs) to switch power on and off to other modules. All things can (and mostly should) be done to save power when running on batteries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was really helpful. I think I have some more questions. What would you suggest to do, if I needed the receiver and temperature module to be on always but other sensors off? What ways are there to do this and how would I connect the solar panel to the battery and the battery to the arduino?

Comment: First: you would connect the solar panel to the charger, then the charger to the battery. The battery then connects (via the charger) to the power supply, which then connects to the Arduino. You can't just wire a solar panel to a battery and hope it will work - charging takes management.

Comment: Second: you choose an RF solution that has a low quiescent current in receive mode and has the ability to wake the Arduino from sleep when needed.

Comment: Ok I will look more into the charging part of the battery. I used the RadioHead library for the radio modules and looked into the docs and found a method that will sleep the receiver or transmitter, I believe. Would that be acceptable? Also how would I "Sleep" the rest of the sensors? `digitalWrite(pin, LOW)`?

Comment: It depends on the sensors. Some you won't need to, some you will be able to instruct to "sleep", and some you will need to cut the power to. A P-channel MOSFET can be used for that, which you can control with a digital IO pin.

Comment: Well in that case I have to first make the circuit, calculate it's Amp output and then calculate what battery will it need if the circuit runs as it is and the recalculate Amp output with most modules sleeping and then see what battery I could use. As you said the solar panel gives an output of 183mA so a battery of 183mAh will charge in 1 hour. How could I effectively charge the 500mAh battery you were talking about that would last about 50 days, if the dht11 and rf receiver are on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105117/discussion-between-filip-and-majenko).

Comment: Current consumption of DHT11 depends on how often you sample it. Receiver current depends on what the receiver is. Note that a solar panel is a current source, and batteries of different types may need a voltage source, current source, or a managed combination of the two. That's what the charge controller is for. For example you will need to convert the solar current source into a voltage source for lead acid batteries.

Comment: You just said a lot of stuff I am not familiar with :P Maybe I could sample the DHT11 every minute? So every 60 seconds the DHT11 sends me the current temperature and humidity and that is stored in my computer, so when I ask it to send me info about the weather then it just shows me the last input I got from the dht and not the actual _current_ weather condition. So I guess the dht11 could be used only once every minute. The receiver is a 433mHz rf module, the most common one. Could you suggest a charge controller that will work in my situation?

Comment: So I found out that my circuit draws up to 1mA so I could use 2 batteries of 3.7V connected upside-down (that is 7.4V) and 500mAh to power the circuit for at least 500 hours, so 20.8 days.

Comment: You won't charge those with your solar panel.

Comment: Why won't they charge?

Comment: You said the solar cell will produce 183mA in 8 hours so, 183mA - 1mA = 182mA left for charging. 182mA / 0.2C = 910mAh capacity. So isn't that enough to power the 500mAh battery??

Comment: You would need to boost the voltage. You only have 6v max...

Comment: How would I boost the voltage?

Comment: With a boost regulator - however that then reduces your available current. This is why I suggested a 3.3V Arduino and a switching regulator since it is more suited to running from the kind of batteries that a 6V solar panel is capable of charging.

Comment: If I had an Arduino UNO R3, but only used it's 3.3V pin, would that be ok?

Comment: No. You can't run a 16MHz Arduino at 3.3v.

Comment: I still need batteries above 5V though and all I can do is get 5 1.2V batteries to get to 6V, to be able to power them with the solar cell. Could that work?

Comment: No. You need a higher voltage than the batteries in order to be able to charge them. I suggest you do a little reading and learning before you start this project.

Comment: I had to find out today what type of battery I needed, that's why I posted such a question here. Could I manage with 4 1.2V batteries to just make it work for a bit?

Comment: 4.8V is fine for a 16MHz Arduino. Read the datasheet for the chip. In the electrical characteristics there's a graph that shows the relationship between the voltage and the maximum supported frequency.

Comment: I saw that the arduino regulates the power so anythin 4V-20V would anyways be regulated so it's fine until the battery drops below 4V?

Comment: No. You do *not* want to use the built in regulator. That is a terrible regulator and will waste lots of power, and won't allow you to run at anything under 6.2V.

Comment: What regulator would I have to use? I just need this to work in theory and probably for a smaller amount of time than days, maybe hours. Wouldn't I be able to charge the battery and run the arduino on 4.8V?

Comment: You don't need a regulator at all. 4.8v is within the specifications of the chip.

Comment: OK then the final circuit will consist of the solar panel connected to the lithium charger, that will be charging the 500mAh 4.8V battery, that will be powering the arduino's circuit that draw 1mA at max estimation. So that will work? Am I could after 1 day of searching for batteries? :P

Comment: The only problem with that scenario is that you shouldn't power a circuit from a lithium battery that is being charged. You risk confusing the charger and over-charging the battery.

Comment: What would you suggest? Charging the battery until it's full and simultaneously powering the arduino, from the solar cell? And if the solar cell goes out then the arduino should draw power from the batteries?

Comment: That is the normal way, yes. The circuit I usually use is the one shown in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293353/load-sharing-charging-circuit-for-lithium-polymer). Most of it is your Li-Ion charger. It's the portion around the battery - Rpull, Q1, and D1 - that forms the interesting part that switches the load's supply for you automatically.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your help and patience. Would getting x2 3.7V batteries lowered down to 5.5V with like a potentiometer work?

Comment: No, but using a high efficiency switching regulator with them would. But then you can't charge them with just 6v.

Comment: So it still wouldn't work? My only option is to find Li-Ion 1.2V batteries?

Comment: No, you have plenty of options. The best one is to not use a 5v Arduino and instead pick one of the more modern 3.3v ones. Then you can use a single li-ion battery.

Comment: Could you name one? I am also in a budget and batteries go for like 9$ which is 27% of it.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I could get 1 lithium battery and use a boosting circuit to get the voltage to 5V to power the arduino. Will the draw increase? Even if it does we should probably be good?

Comment: There are arduinos specifically designed for low power use of lithium batteries. Check the website.